# Implementing Catenaries and related curves

Tags: math, excel, excel-formula, curves, vba

Hello first of all I would just like to say that I wouldn't like the answer I would just like to know the method of doing these kinds of equations, because I have been asked to implement this into a macro for excel and have difficulty understanding them.

an example would be s = 12/x + x

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Tell us what part you are having trouble with.  Caternary curves or excel-macros?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Sorry man, I'll try elsewhere.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Just the Caternary curves, I would know how to write the code if I was able to figure out how to do the maths (Maths isn't my strong point). Thanks

Comment: Then this is probably off-topic for here.  Not because of what @RowladShaw said, it *is* about programming.  But rather because the help you are specifically asking for is too introductory/tutorial and is more about the math.  It is unclear to me how we would help you here *without* just giving you the answer, per your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ? Here Excel does the math for you ... 
[image]

Now you could probably ask: "I want to enter the symbolic formula and want to see it developed in Excel for a range of X that I enter, too - with table and graph"